# Jenkins 0 How to fix: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence?

Tags: java, jenkins, sax

After running jenkins from the war and making an agent, I get the parse error (please see below).

Looking at character encodongs:

```
root@rays8350:/mnt/d/jenkins/jenkins-home# find -name "*.xml" | xargs chardetect3 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sort | uniq --count
     19  ascii with confidence 1.0
```

There is noting in the agent root except for a skeleton.

I have had this problem before on a jenkins that had jobs. Sometime it would find a problem with byte 1 of a 1 byte sequence.

Any pointers will be aprecciated.

```
d:\jenkins\chief>java -jar ../jars/agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://localhost:8080/computer/agent-99/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret @my-secret.
txt -workDir "d:\jenkins-agent-99"
May 15, 2021 9:58:33 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using d:\jenkins-agent-99\remoting as a remoting work directory
May 15, 2021 9:58:33 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to d:\jenkins-agent-99\remoting
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:262)
```

Edit 1: Seems to only happen when I add a secret:

```
+ java -jar ../jars/agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://192.168.1.6:8089/computer/agent-86/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret a03f090362274d4eac1fd1e7c829
7af9 -workDir 'c:\agent-86'
May 20, 2021 1:31:01 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using c:\agent-86\remoting as a remoting work directory
May 20, 2021 1:31:01 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to c:\agent-86\remoting
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:261)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.loadDom(Launcher.java:609)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:549)
```

Comment: Maybe the file is not UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: it looks like non of them are (at least chardetect3 thinks so) . this is before any jobs have been created. i just made one agent and tried to connect it.

Comment: I have no idea how jnlp works, but my reading of the code suggests that it's your decrypted jnlp file that's not valid xml. You only looked at `/mnt/d/jenkins/jenkins-home/**/*.xml` which would not detect this.  Maybe the file is not encrypted, or maybe your key is wrong?

Comment: In my case it was just an invalid `-secret` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exception, fixed it by re-generate the file "secret-file". Command like `echo {secret get from Jenkins controller} > secret-file`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this check list helped me:

- Validate if jenkins node is not disabled in the master

  - [image]
- Validate if node name in the url is not encoded.

  - My node name was **acme_dev**
  - But the jenkins suggested me this url
  - `https://jenkins.acme.com/manage/computer/acme%5Fdev/jenkins-agent.jnlp`
  - I changed acme%5Fdev for acme_dev and it worked

### Additional

- Java versions is not a problem