# Why is my jenkins agent logging a fatal error but staying connected - illegal byte sequence error

Tags: java, jenkins

I am running the jenkins agent via systemd. Here is the unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jenkins Agent

[Service]
User=myuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/jenkins
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/myuser/jenkins/start-jenkins-agent.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Started with `sudo systemctl enable jenkins-agent.service` then `sudo systemctl start jenkins-agent.service`. Here is the `start-jenkins-agent.sh` script:

```
cd /home/myuser/jenkins
# secret-file must be present in this folder and contain the secret key
# Just in case we would have upgraded the controller, we need to make sure that the agent is using the latest version of the agent.jar
curl -sO https://myinfra.mysite.io/jenkins/jnlpJars/agent.jar
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://myinfra.mysite.io/jenkins/manage/computer/myServer2/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret @secret-file -workDir /home/myuser/jenkins
exit 0
```

`secret-file` is present and I generated it by `echo 'secret_here' > secret-file` as instructed by the Jenkins server.

Previously this was running in a `screen` session and didn't log much other than startup logs, then nothing else. And that worked fine. Since moving to systemd, though, I notice some strange logs.

First off `journalctl -u jenkins-agent` shows the same logs as when I had the `screen` session, and there are no errors. Furthermore, I check the agent connectivity status on the Jenkins server and it is always connected and runs builds with no problems.

However, when I run `journalctl -f` I notice a lot more logs from jenkins and java. This loops about every 20-30 seconds:

```
systemd[739]: jenkins-agent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[739]: jenkins-agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[739]: jenkins-agent.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1618834.
systemd[739]: Stopped Jenkins Agent for myinfra.
systemd[739]: Started Jenkins Agent for myinfra.
java[994857]: Dec 12, 2023 9:11:07 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
java[994857]: INFO: Using /home/myuser/jenkins/remoting as a remoting work directory
java[994857]: Dec 12, 2023 9:11:07 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
java[994857]: INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/myuser/jenkins/remoting
java[994857]: [Fatal Error] :1:1: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
java[994857]: Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:262)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
java[994857]:         at hudson.remoting.Launcher.loadDom(Launcher.java:604)
java[994857]:         at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:546)
java[994857]:         at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:346)
java[994857]:         at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:297)
java[994857]: Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:702)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:568)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1699)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1565)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1603)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:158)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:860)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
java[994857]:         at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
java[994857]:         ... 6 more
systemd[739]: jenkins-agent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[739]: jenkins-agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I cannot find anything about a non-utf8 file and I do not know what file it it trying to parse and failing.

Here is the java version on the server:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Why are the logs for `journalctl -u jenkins-agent` showing no problems, but clearly according to `journalctl` I can see `jenkins-agent.service` is flapping?
2. Is this actually a problem, besides log spam?
3. How can I address this problem with the `Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.`?

Comment: Does the version of Java on the Agent match with the version of Java on Master? Difference in JVM versions can cause issues.

Comment: Possible duplicated
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553413/jenkins-0-how-to-fix-invalid-byte-2-of-2-byte-utf-8-sequence

Comment: @mikequentel Both servers have same version: `openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)`. @JoaoVitorino That question had a solution to regenerate the secret file, but that did not solve it for me, and I confirm that my secret file has the proper contents and it's valid UTF8.

Comment: @swagrov Even though you have set `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, there might be other locale or character encoding settings in the system or Java environment affecting the process. Verify the settings for `LC_ALL` and other locale-related environment variables. In the Java command line, explicitly set the character encoding to UTF-8. You can do this by adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the Java command in your `start-jenkins-agent.sh` script.

Comment: @VonC `LC_ALL` is unset. I added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and that had no effect on the error outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and enable [verbose logging](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-logging/configuration.html) in your `start-jenkins-agent.sh` script, which might provide additional insights into the issue.

```bash
cd /home/myuser/jenkins
curl -sO https://myinfra.mysite.io/jenkins/jnlpJars/agent.jar

# Enable verbose logging
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/myuser/jenkins/logging.properties"

java $JAVA_OPTS -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://myinfra.mysite.io/jenkins/manage/computer/myServer2/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret @secret-file -workDir /home/myuser/jenkins
exit 0
```

You would need to create a `logging.properties` file in the specified directory with appropriate logging levels set.

Check also the contents of the JNLP file (valid and properly formatted) and the `secret-file` for any anomalies or non-UTF-8 characters.
Make sure `secret-file` is saved in UTF-8 encoding. You can use [`iconv`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iconv-command-in-linux-with-examples/) or a similar tool to check and convert the file encoding if necessary.

Note: the difference in log outputs ([`journalctl -u` vs `journalctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journalctl.html)) might be due to the way `systemd` handles and redirects output.

- `journalctl -u jenkins-agent` might be showing only the standard output or a filtered view,
- whereas `journalctl -f` provides a real-time, unfiltered view of all system logs, including errors and system messages.

---

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648042/why-is-my-jenkins-agent-logging-a-fatal-error-but-staying-connected-illegal-by/77663883#comment136933792_77663883), I believe we can rule out issues with the `secret-file` and the basic setup of the Jenkins agent. The fact that you are seeing specific errors when you intentionally use an incorrect secret confirms that the secret is being read and used correctly.

Since you have confirmed that the JNLP file is UTF-8 encoded when downloaded locally, it is worth checking if the same holds true when the file is downloaded on the server.
Run the `curl` command from your `start-jenkins-agent.sh` script directly on the server and inspect the downloaded JNLP file.

- Use the `file` command to check the encoding: `file -i jenkins-agent.jnlp`.
- Use a text editor or the `cat` command to visually inspect the file for any anomalies.

The error `cannot load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler"` suggests a problem with the logging configuration. It is possible that the logger is trying to write to a file but lacks permissions or the specified path is incorrect.

- Make sure the directory for the log file exists and is writable by the user running the Jenkins agent.
- Consider using absolute paths in the `logging.properties` file for file handlers.

The issue might be influenced by the system environment under which the Jenkins agent is running, especially since it was previously running in a `screen` session without issues. Check for environment variables that might be different between the `screen` session and the systemd service context. Particularly, look for variables related to Java or character encoding, like `JAVA_OPTS`, `LANG`, `LC_*`.

As a diagnostic step, try running the Jenkins agent manually using the same command from the `start-jenkins-agent.sh` script. That might reveal issues related to the `systemd` environment. If it runs successfully when started manually, compare the environment variables and system context between the manual run and the `systemd` service.

---

Based on "[Jenkins 0 How to fix: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67553413/6309)" mentioned by [Joao Vitorino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4175515/joao-vitorino):

Make sure the secret file is correctly encoded in UTF-8, and regenerate it: `echo {secret} > secret-file`, replacing `{secret}` with the actual secret key obtained from the Jenkins controller.

Make sure the JNLP file downloaded by the agent is the correct and complete file, and check the encoding of the JNLP file to make sure it is UTF-8.

Also, inspect the JNLP file for any formatting issues or unexpected content that might cause parsing errors. Use an XML validator tool to check if the JNLP file is well-formed.

Comment: I set `logging.properties` with `.level = ALL` and there are no logs generated outside of what I mentioned in the question. Inside `/home/myuser/jenkins/remoting` I see files like `remoting.log.4.1` but they are empty. I also tried with the logging settings specified here https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/configure-loggers-for-jenkins-agents and had the same results.

Not sure how to check the JNLP file. I download it locally from the URL in the startup command and it's UTF8 for me and has no bad characters. Secrets file is UTF8, too.

Comment: I also see error `Can't load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler"`

Comment: handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST

This worked out, but gave no helpful logs relating to the file error.

Comment: To give some more info - if I add "x" to the secret-file so it's wrong, the agent correctly fails to connect at all, and if I remove the "x" then it does connect, and then starts giving the error logs above. This is why I am sure the secret-file is fine.

How could I check the JNLP file? Maybe what the server that's running the agent downloads is different then what I get locally from that URL? I can't see how, though.

Comment: @swagrov I have edited the answer to add some debugging suggestions.

Comment: Would you know how I could curl the jnlp url? If I just curl the url I get (as I expect) missing authentication error.

Comment: @swagrov I use `curl -Lk -u adminUser:password https://myKenkins/computer/myNode/jenkins-agent.jnlp`

Comment: In the old screen session, the only relevant env var in that list is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, (there are LC color options as well), so I `export` that value in the startup script but still same issue. I don't have the admin password, but if I curl that with bogus creds I get an <html> doc with the 401 error. If I echo that into a file and do `file -i test.jnlp` it shows `text/html; charset=us-ascii` which is UTF8. We have google auth set up so I cannot use my own user credentials to curl. And using the logging settings did not give any more information.

Comment: Running the script in a terminal session shows the same logs as `journalctl -u jenkins-agent`, the logs that indicate no problems. I see `INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect` then `INFO: Connected`.

Comment: @swagrov 401: you need to use an account with the privilege to access that URL.

Comment: Ah I got it after creating an API key for my user and using my email. The output file is like `<jnlp><application-desc><argument>etcetc...` as expected and `file -i test.jnlp` shows `test.jnlp: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`